# How to use Hibernate 5.2.10 MySQL JSON support without AttributeConverter or customUserType to map to Java Entity Class?

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to map the MySQL JSON column to Java Entity class. Looking for the cleanest way of doing this.

Upon doing some research found 3 possible ways:

1. Extending AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType
2. Create a custom UserType
3. Use an attribute Converter

I used an attribute converter to convert the JSON column from String (as MySQL driver makes it to a String) to my required type -  this works with both the Hibernate V4.3.10 and V5.2.10

I tried to find if JSON is natively supported in Hibernate and found the PR https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/1395, based on the PR looks like it does add JSON mapping to the MySQL Dialect hence letting Hibernate know about the JSON Column.

**Does this mean I can use something like this to map to JSON Column in DB ?**`@Column(name="json_type_column")
 Private Object correspondingJsonAttribute;`

If I cannot use it like this and need to use one of the above 3 methods, is there a reason I would need to upgrade to get the `registerColumnType( Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "json" );` which is part of the PR and is present in Hibernate V5.2.10, **Do I get any more features from V5.2.10 that support JSON columns?**

I also looked into the corresponding test case to understand how the JSON column mapping is being done https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/bytecode/enhancement/access/MixedAccessTestTask.java, this uses @Access annotation via property, looks like it sets the corresponding JSON column variable in Entity to Map after converting it from String.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Upon doing some research found 3 possible ways:
>
> - Extending AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType
> - Create a custom UserType
> - Use an attribute Converter

`AttributeConvertor` won't help you for this, but you can still use a [custom `UserType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-basic-type-using-hibernate-usertype/), or [Hibernate Type Descriptors](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/).

> Does this mean I can use something like this to map to JSON Column in
> DB?
>
> ```
> @Column(name="json_type_column")  Private Object
> correspondingJsonAttribute;
> ```

No. The `json` type is just for JDBC so that Hibernate knows how to handle that JDBC object when setting a parameter on a `PreparedStatement` or when fetching a `ResultSet`.

> Do I get any more features from V5.2.10 that support JSON columns?

No, but you just need to supply [your own JSON type](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/).

You can just use the [`hibernate-types`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-types-open-source-project-is-born/) which is available on Maven Central.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And use the provided `JdonType` from Hibernate Types as it works on MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or H2 without doing any modifications.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response @vlad, I have couple more questions, trying to quickly test somethings related to this, will update here after that.

Comment: I am trying to understand why attributeConverter is not a solution for this, so built a [sample application](https://github.com/smpti/mysql-json-test/tree/master) with both approaches to understand the differences. It seems to have the same result ? Can you please guide me here.

Comment: Having attribute converter would require me to have a converter for each new type I need, is there any other negative other than this ? My [converter](https://github.com/smpti/mysql-json-test/blob/v_with-attribute_converter-hibernate5.2.10-jdbc5.1.42/src/main/java/com/example/jsonSupport/JsonObjectToLinkedHashMapConverter.java)  is based on [this one](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/)